# 'subset' not working for drop_duplicates pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    A                B    C               D     NEW
0   1       Adhoc_Task  WID          WI_DTL      []  
1   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT           IXN_1  (IXN,)
2   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT          IXN_10  (IXN,)
3   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT         IXN_100  (IXN,)
4   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT         IXN_101  (IXN,)
5   2    Batch_Support  ATT      CDS_STATUS      []
6   2    Batch_Support  ATT     CDS_CONTROL      []
7   2    Batch_Support  ATT  CDS_ORA_STATUS      []
8   2    Batch_Support  ATT      REP_FILTER      []
9   1      online_load  ATT           TAX_3  (TAX,)
10  1      online_load  ATT           TAX_4  (TAX,)
11  1      online_load  ATT           TAX_8  (TAX,)
12  1      online_load  ATT          TAX_11  (TAX,)
```

Desired output would look like this:

```
    A                B    C               D     NEW
0   1       Adhoc_Task  WID          WI_DTL      []  
1   1  Arun_adhoc_load  ATT           IXN_1  (IXN,)
5   2    Batch_Support  ATT      CDS_STATUS      []
9   1      online_load  ATT           TAX_3  (TAX,)
```

I'm trying to drop duplicate rows based off column B. However, when I run

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['B'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: drop_duplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subset'
```

I'm running pandas 0.19.1 from python 3, so I took a look at the documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

I haven't the foggiest of what I'm doing wrong with `subset`. How would I drop duplicates from the DataFrame based off the values in one column?

Comment: For me it works perfectly. But you can try `df.drop_duplicates(['B'], inplace=True)` or `df.drop_duplicates('B', inplace=True)`

Comment: I tried that... I got the following error: `ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False`

Comment: I also tried that. I get the following: `TypeError: drop_duplicates() got multiple values for argument 'keep'`

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize subset as a keyword, or recognize the argument positionally either.

Comment: @jezrael you're right. It was a series. Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For whatever reason in your code, df became a Series object. Check `type(df)` just before the failing `drop_duplicates` call. That function has no `subset` argument for the Series.

Comment: Super, nice answer. +1

Comment: You have to wonder why the pandas error code doesn't suggest this...

Comment: Pandas maintainers will likely welcome a PR from you with this suggestion as code change.

Comment: Another reason for this message (not in OP's case), is if you forget the brackets [] as in this example: df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'B', keep='first', inplace=True)